# How can I make Google Maps show me foregin countries in English (with English letters) in the Google Chrome browser?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

In Chrome every location is written in it's native form and I can't read cyrillic or Chinese.  If I open Google Maps in IE the names appear in English but who wants to use IE for anything ever?  Google's forums were unhelpful and a message to them was unanswered.  Is there a plug-in or something for Chrome to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know - all you need to do is click on the top right corner drop-down button - and then click on "English" - that turns all the text to English.
Works for me :)

[image: Here is screenshot]

Comment: Duh yep that works.  I clicked around but I never noticed that up there before.

Comment: There is no such drop-down! Can you post a screen-cast?

Answer (score 3):

The **option** can be found in the **upper-right dropdown** in the maps region (not top navbar).. what you're looking for is the dropdown arrow (below 'Traffic'), where you can select to show things like 'Weather', 'Labels', etc. - 'English' is also one of the options, select it (adds a check mark next to the option). By doing so, the **names on the map will all change to English.**